# Print given string character by character

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;

public class Reverse {

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
{
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {   
        String s = scanner.next();
        char output='\0';

        for(int j=0;j>=s.length()-1;j++)
        {
            output = s.charAt(j);
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to print a string character by character with the above program, but it's not working - it shows no syntax errors, warnings or output.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'not working'? Is there a runtime error? Does your output not match what you expected and if so, what input values are you using?

Comment: input: 2 asd aswe . output:blank

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your for statement is incorrect. That part specifies a condition which must be *true* before the next iteration of your loop is executed. Try flipping the arrow around:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= s.length() - 1; j++)
```